# How to align button to stay at the bottom of page and avoid keyboard in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, user-interface, mobile

How can I keep the button at the absolute bottom of the viewable screen, while also avoiding the keyboard?

Right now the button is jumping up the screen when I open the keyboard.

I have tried using `position: "absolute", bottom: "0"` for the button element too, and that did not have any effect on the position of the button.

Here is my code:

```
 return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior="padding"
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="First name (required)"
          onChangeText={(name) =>
            setFirstName((prev) => name)
          }
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Last name (optional)"
          onChangeText={(lastname) =>
            setFirstName((prev) => lastname)
          }
          style={styles.input}
        />
      </View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => null}
        title="Next"
        buttonStyle={styles.button}
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: 350,
    top: "20%",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  input: {
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
    height: 50,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    width: 300,
    marginBottom: 80,
    height: 50,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});
```

This is how it looks when I open the keyboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing the behaviour, instead of padding put "height" because the keyboardAvoidingView style has space between so that could be the issue.

Comment: @TawandaMuzavazi It seems like a step in the right direction, but I still can't control the button.

Comment: This is an Android, right?  Try changing `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `"adjustPan"` in your AndroidManifest.xml, and rebuild the app.  I believe it is `"adjustResize"` by default and RN doesn't seem to handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the avoiding view is different for both platforms.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior= {Platform.OS === "ios"? "padding":"height"}
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <StatusBar style="light" />
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="First name (required)"
              onChangeText={(name) =>
                setFirstName((prev) => name)
              }
              style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Last name (optional)"
              onChangeText={(lastname) =>
                setFirstName((prev) => lastname)
              }
              style={styles.input}
            />
          </View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => null}
            title="Next"
            buttonStyle={styles.button}
          />
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Otherwise if you need more control over the keyboard behavior you can pragmatically change the default behavior using this package.

[React-Native-Android-Keyboard-Adjust](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust) - I have used this package in few of the places and it helps in most of the cases.

*Note: Package works on android only*